# SQL to get the most recently created record based on Datetime from Data extension in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

How to get the most recently created record based on datetime using SQL in marketing cloud?

### Sql:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Name,
    Email,
    DateTime
FROM
    DateBasedDE
ORDER BY
    DateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this query

```
SELECT 
 Name, Email, DateTime FROM (
SELECT   Name, Email, DateTime, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS RowNumber FROM 
 Unique_data_AM_01) t1
 WHERE t1.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you